# Why do backgrounded processes sometimes stop spontaneously?

Tags: terminal, io, job-control, background-process

Sometimes, some time after I've backgrounded a process with `bg` in bash, when I press Enter in the same shell to redisplay the prompt (just to check that I'm still in bash when some output from the background process has been displayed), the background process seems to stop spontaneously.

If I do `bg` again the same problem recurs.

The only way to fix it seems to be `fg`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Where is your output going?  Are you filling a buffer somewhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This usually happens if the process tries to read from its `stdin` stream. When the process is in the background, it receives a [TTIN signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTIN) and is thus frozen (same behavior as a STOP signal). There is also the dual signal [TTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTTOU) when a background process tries to write to its terminal.

Bringing it to the foreground resumes the process and allows it to read from your terminal.

Demo:

```
$ cat t.sh
#! /bin/sh
sleep 1
read dummy
$ ./t.sh &
[1] 3364
$ 
[1]+  Stopped                 ./t.sh
$ ps aux|grep t.sh
me  3364  0.0  0.0  11268  1200 pts/0    T    17:04   0:00 /bin/sh ./t.sh
```

One of the ways of avoiding this is to use [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), but this can have strange effects if the program doesn't deal with having its input stream redirected to `/dev/null`.