# top, top&, top & commands in linux

Tags: linux, background-process, top

i don't understand the difference between "top, top&, top &"   commands in linux. [image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 8):

The `&` character at the end of a command, no matter if it's preceded by a space or not, will start a background process (sometimes also called an *asyncrounous process* since the shell will not wait for it to terminate before executing the next command).

Running `top` as a background process makes little sense as it is, by default, an interactive program.  This is also why you see the text `Stopped` in the terminal as soon as the backgrounded `top` tries to interact with the user (it can't, because it's not connected to the controlling terminal).

On my system, I get a slightly more descriptive message:

```
[1] + Stopped (tty output) top
```

meaning "`top` tried to write something to the terminal, but couldn't, so it's been stopped temporarily".

To move the backgrounded `top` into the foreground, use `fg`.

---

In this case, you have *two* backgrounded `top` processes running. To foreground the first, use `fg %1`. To foreground the second, use `fg %2`.

The numbers in `%1` and `%2` are job IDs, or job specifications.  These corresponds to the numbers in square brackets displayed when you started the background jobs.

---

Related:

- [What does "fg" stand for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352032/what-does-fg-stand-for)
- [How to suspend and bring a background process to foreground](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/how-to-suspend-and-bring-a-background-process-to-foreground)
- [Why do backgrounded processes sometimes stop spontaneously?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/why-do-backgrounded-processes-sometimes-stop-spontaneously)

... and other questions related to the [job-control](/questions/tagged/job-control) tag.

Answer (score 3):

`top&` and `top &` do the same thing.

They'll both run top as a background task (which in case of top is not very useful)

In your screenshot this is shown by `[1] 4679` and you can get the process into the foreground by using `fg 1`.

You can read more on that Topic [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all top& and top & are same thing as & is used to run processes in background. The only difference between top and top& or top & is simple top will be running as process on your screen and top& or top & will run as background process.