# cat<tmp.1|wc>tmp.3

Tags: linux, pipe

Anyone please explain the following output..[image]
cattmp.3

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
cat<tmp.1|wc>tmp.3
```

This is the same as

```
wc <tmp.1 >tmp3
```

It will count the number of words, lines and bytes in `tmp.1` and write the result to `tmp.3`. This command line produces no output on the terminal when run in this way.

The other output saying `Done` is from an earlier invocation of `ls` that was run as a background job (started as `ls ... &`). That job finished just as you ran the `wc` command, and the shell reported that it had done so.

---

Judging from this question and from [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396634/top-top-top-commands-in-linux), you seem to run odd commands as background jobs. Don't do that. Simply don't run commands with `&` appended to the end if you don't need to run them as asynchronous processes.

Look for a tutorial on-line that explains job control in `bash`, or read the [job-control](/questions/tagged/job-control) questions here.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat<tmp.1|wc>tmp.3
```

This counts the bytes in `tmp.1`, writing the result into `tmp.3` and printing nothing. It is equivalent to

```
wc <tmp.1 >tmp.3
```

or

```
<tmp.1 wc >tmp.3
```

The output that you see printed, that is:

```
[3] Done         ls --color=auto -al | wc
```

is the shell telling you that a previous command you had run in the background (with `&`) has completed.