# Why would a backgrounded job with `| less` be stopped, while the other one without it is running?

Tags: bash, pipe, background-process

```
$ pdfgrep -R -i spark . | less &
$ pdfgrep -R -i spark . &

$ jobs
[3]-  Stopped                 pdfgrep -R -i spark . | less
[4]   Running                 pdfgrep -R -i spark . &
```

1. Why would the one with `| less` be stopped, while the other one
   without it is running?

   The stopped backgrounded job doesn't read from stdin. So that can't be the reason.
2. The reason that I background the jobs is that I can do something
   else in the same terminal session.

   The reason that I pipe to `less` is because I don't want the output
   to stdout messes up the screen of my terminal session when I am
   doing something else.

   Is there some way to achieve the two goals above? I slightly prefer
   not saving output to a file  over saving output to a file, because it takes a little more to remember the file, read and delete them.

Thanks.

Comment: `less`  reads from stdin only when I type some commands of `less`, such as `q`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why dont you use output redirect if you dont want it in console?

Comment: @jorgee How?...

Comment: using `pdfgrep -R -i spark . > /dev/null 2>&1` I don't remember if the & for background goes before the first > or after the 1. I don't have Linux atm. This will send stderr to stdout (terminal by default), but then stdout to /dev/null, discarding it

Comment: I need the output

Comment: You can use `screen` to have background sessions

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587526/111181

Answer (score 17):

Let's look more closely at what's happening to `less`:

```
$ pdfgrep -R -i spark . | strace less &
[...]
open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)  = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
```

Job control restricts the processes in a background job from performing certain operations on the controlling terminal.

- If a background process tries to read from the terminal, it will be sent a `SIGTTIN` signal, which typically stops (pauses) the process.
- If a background process tries to set a terminal's parameters, it will be sent a `SIGTTOU` signal, which also typically stops the process. **That's what is happening here with the `TCSETSW` [ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html)**. The `less` program tries to put the terminal into raw mode soon after it starts, even before it knows whether it has anything to display.

  There is a good reason for this: you don't want a background job asynchronously changing your terminal so that, for example, raw mode is on and echo is off.
  (A background process can *get* terminal parameters with the `TCGETS` ioctl without being stopped - see the listing above.)
- If a background process tries to write to the terminal and the terminal has the `tostop` flag set, it will be sent the `SIGTTOU` signal.

You probably don't have the `tostop` flag set (run `stty -a` to check). If you don't, a background command like `pdfgrep -R -i spark . &` that doesn't change any terminal settings will be able to write to your terminal whenever it tries.

You also wrote:

> The reason that I pipe to less is because I don't want the output to stdout messes up the screen of my terminal session when I am doing something else

The less program is ultimately going to send output to the terminal, one screenful at a time. If you run `stty tostop` before `pdfgrep | less &`, or before `pdfgrep &`, then they will only output to your terminal when they are in the foreground.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your second question:  I use screen(1) to multiplex many commands through one tty-like device.

- [Homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and [Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/index.html) -- It's a GNU project.
- ["10 Screen Command Examples to Manage Linux Terminals"](https://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/)

There is at least one [alternative](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_termmux.php), tmux(1) and a simplifying wrapper for both, byobu(1).

Answer (score 5):

`less` is trying to interact with (output to) the TTY, but since it's running as a background job, it has no TTY to write to. The `pdfgrep` utility, on the other hand, writes to standard output.

On my system, I get the slightly more descriptive output

```
$ cat ~/.profile | less &
[1] 51758 67354
$
[1] + Done                 cat ~/.profile |
      Stopped (tty output) less
```

In this simple example, `cat` finishes sending my `.profile` to `less`, but `less` is unable to display it since it's a background job. Hence the `Stopped (tty output) less` message.

The `less` process is still running though. It's only *temporarilly* stopped.  To switch to it, use `fg %1` (the number corresponds to the job number reported in square brackets in the "stopped" message, and it should also have been reported when you started the job).

---

Related: [top, top&, top & commands in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396634/top-top-top-commands-in-linux)

Comment: Thanks. But I remember a background job can output to stdout without being paused, and it is stopped only when trying to read from stdin.

Comment: `cat ~/.profile` also outputs to tty too, but `cat ~/.profile &` won't stop it.

Comment: @Tim What makes you think `less` sends its output to its standard output?

Comment: @Tim No, `cat` outputs to standard output. `less` needs a controlling terminal. It's an interactive program.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way for my question in part 2?

Comment: @Tim Did so now. You can switch to `less` with `fg %3` (in this example).

Comment: Is it possible to keep it running in background so that I can do something else?

Comment: @Tim You may avoid putting it in the foreground at all, or if you do, just press `Ctrl+Z` to suspend it again.

Comment: Thanks. "`less` is trying to interact with (output to) the TTY, but since it's running as a background job, it has no TTY to write to. The `pdfgrep` utility, on the other hand, writes to standard output." "`cat` outputs to standard output. `less` needs a controlling terminal. It's an interactive program."  What is the difference between "outputs to standard output" and "needs a controlling  terminal and is an interactive program"? Is the latter equal to "outputs to standard output" plus "inputs from standard input"? Or is the output part of the latter still different from the former?

Comment: @Tim Yes, different. `less` writes directly to the `tty`. Since the `tty` is connected to the foreground process, not to `less`, it has to stop until it's "handed back" to `less` again (using `fg`). Writing to standard output does not have that restriction, unless it happens to be redirected to the `tty` (see for example `cat >$(tty) &` which will have the same issue as `less` has).